# Find and delete text, then insert an image with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoticons

im trying to replace text with an image using jquery or javascript. for example

```
<div id="log">
<p>this is a :) happy face</p>
<p>this is a :( sad face</p>
<p>these are :/ x( :P other faces</p>
</div>
```

ive attempted a few things but either i end up replacing the entire string or the browser does not render the image and instead displays the html

```
this is a <img src="happy.png"> face
```

this is for a chat application im messing with and im fairly new so if you can include some explanation in your code thatd help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could look like (using jQuery):

```
$('div#log').find('p').html(function( html ) {
    return html.replace(':)', '<img src="happy.png"/>');
});
```

Obivously this should get a little more sophisticated. I could imagine a lookup object where you link strings to images, for instance:

```
var myMap = {
    '\\:\\)': 'happy.png',  // need to escape those for regex
    '\\:\\(': 'sad.png',
    '\\:\\/': 'other.png'
};

$('div#log').find('p').html(function( _, html ) {
    for(var face in myMap) {
        html = html.replace( new RegExp( face, 'g' ), '<img src="' + myMap[ face ] + '"/>' );
    }
    return html;
});
```

Comment: +1 good solution. You don't need to escape the `:` or ``/``. Actually I'm not sure what happens if you have an invalid escape character sequence in an expression. Could be that it then tries to match ``\`` and `:` literally, so it would even "break" the expression.

Comment: very nice. your code works really well, is a robust solution and much thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
<div id="log">
<p id='my'>this is a :) happy face</p>
<p>this is a :( sad face</p>
<p>these are :/ x( :P other faces</p>
</div>

var p = $('#my').html();
var r = p.replace(':)', '<img src="happy.jpg">');
$('#my').html(r);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PuDMx/

Comment: with a little modification, your code works nicely. instead of adding an id to the paragraph tags, i used the p:last selector. because the paragraphs are being added dynamically, and they are not unique, they dont get an id.